# How much damage does Produce Flame do when cast from a Flaming Star?

Tags: spells, magic-items, pathfinder-2e

A [Flaming Star](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1014) lets you cast [Produce Flame](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=236), which does (at the level when you can get the item) 2d4+(your spellcasting ability modifier) damage.

The question is, how much is *"your spellcasting ability modifier"* in this case:

- **2:** This is a level 3 item, and its spell attack roll is +7. Assuming it has *trained* proficiency<sup>1</sup>, it need a +2 spellcasting ability modifier for the math to work
- **Your spellcasting ability modifier:** Spellhearts can use your spell attack roll or spell DC, so it is easiest to handle as if Produce Flame was one of your cantrips
- **Your Charism:** cantrips gained through Spellhearts are quite similar to innate spells, and they use Charisma
- **Other**

---

1. Most likely on level 3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Damage Depends on How you Cast a Spell

Activating this spellheart uses the Cast a Spell activity, which [requires](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=100) that the user already has some form of spellcasting:

> If an item lists “Cast a Spell” after “Activate,” the activation requires you to use the Cast a Spell activity to Activate the Item. This happens when the item replicates a spell. **You must have a spellcasting class feature to Activate an Item with this activation component.**

The ability modifier for this spell would be the same as whatever the user already has for their spellcasting.

Comment: So a base Fighter cannot use a spellheart?

Comment: @SpearCarrier.no2 that... appears to be the RAW case, yes. This is an excellent spot, Brandon!

A base fighter could theoretically not use the spell heart, although presumably even an investment as small as [Arcane Sense](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=754) would let them qualify (or [Trick Magic Item](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=857) if you don't want to use Charisma, but that's much riskier). Not sure I'm a big fan of this being the rules, tbh; I'd probably let non-spellcasters just pretend they have innate spellcasting (trained + Charisma), but that'd be outside the rules.

Comment: They could not Activate it, but they could still benefit from passive effects like the *flaming star's* fire resistance when affixed to armor. Whether something like Trick Magic Item would allow Activation might be a good separate question.